# Java Non-Blocking IO ObjectStream

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, java-8, nio

I have seen that there are some questions about this topic, but they are all a couple years old or not very elaborate.

I have been migrating an applications old `Socket` implementation to the new NIO `SocketChannel`, because it was working unstable and I was going to do this part again (as part of a code-review). So now I am using Non-Blocking `SocketChannel`, and just found out that I can't just use the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` because... well it's non-blocking.
Apparently the SocketChannel needs to have a size for the transferred data.

Is there a known solution about this problem? Is there maybe a template one can use, or a solution that is commonly approved as best practice (*pattern*)? The fact that I can just utilize `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` made everything a lot easier. If I have to create my own implementation, I will probably need too much time and break a lot of things in an application I'm trying to make more stable.

Questions in a summary:

- Is there a common solution to use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` in a non-blocking `SocketChannel`?
- Can I maybe even make a hybrid, like accepting the incoming connections in non-blocking mode and when the selector finds out that there is stuff to read, it changes to blocking-mode? (I know it sounds terrible, but I am a bit desperate.)

PS: Using Java 8 and it's a TCP-Stream.

Comment: Migrating to NIO is no way to solve an instability problem. You will almost certainly only make it worse. You should solve the original problem, not write a whole bunch of new code.

Comment: @EJP the migration was not to solve the instability problem. It is mainly to make everything more efficient. Instead of putting effort into reviewing parts of "old" implementations, I was trying to make everything better overall. Because I was going to migrate to NIO anyways sooner or later (that was the plan).

Comment: Your question says exactly what I mentioned: 'because of an instability problem'. In any case you won't find much speed benefit from using NIO, and you will find integrating it with Object streams very difficult indeed. I suggest you don't. Strongly.

Comment: @EJP No, my question is something else. I just said that to clarify my reasons why I am trying to change to NIO. The instability problem is because the application is still in early development and the network part was just a placeholder until it gets revised. I was going to do the revision now and was going to change to NIO. Maybe I said something unclear. My question is if I can make ObjectInput- and ObjectOutputStream work with non-blocking SocketChannels easily or not. I think that has been already said now. Thanks.

Comment: @EJP By the way, is there any reason why Java did not make the non-blocking mode compatible with the Object Serializations? For me this is a design flaw.

Comment: I can only repeat what I've already said. Your project seems very poorly motivated and even more poorly understood. Bloking I/O with object streams is one of the easiest forms of communication to program on the planet. By contrast, Serialization via non-blocking I/O is complex and wastes time and space at the sender. Don't do this.

Comment: @EJP My free-time project is growing slowly and I am not doing hard engineering here. I am using it to learn more about programming and Java (I come from .NET). So yes, it may be poorly understood. That's the idea of it. It is a distributed sound system, where I have implemented different types of protocols just for the purpose of learning. If I decide to make this project open source, you're more than welcome to make everything perfect. Right now I want to understand the advantages and disadvantages and problems that may occur.

Answer (score 2):

> I am using Non-Blocking SocketChannel, and just found out that I can't just use the ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream because... well it's non-blocking.

SocketChannel is blocking by default. If you don't want non-blocking, don't configure it that way.

ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream are much simpler to use with plain Java IO.

> Apparently the SocketChannel needs to have a size for the transferred data.

You don't have to, but if you are using an Object*Stream it is simpler.

> Is there a known solution about this problem?

Part from using plain IO, or using a a block of data with a length before it using NIO.

If you want to improve performance, I suggest using another serialization library. The built in one is one of the slowest options.  There is dozens of alternatives (in fact I have written two ;)

> Is there maybe a template one can use, or a solution that is commonly approved as best practice (pattern)?

Using Plain IO, and a faster serializer.

> The fact that I can just utilize ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream made everything a lot easier.

In that case you don't want to be using NIO as it will make things ten time harder, esp if you use non-blocking IO and Selectors.

> If I have to create my own implementation, I will probably need too much time and break a lot of things in an application I'm trying to make more stable.

Agreed, esp when there is so many alternatives to chose from.

> Is there a common solution to use ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream in a non-blocking SocketChannel?

Not at all.

> Can I maybe even make a hybrid, like accepting the incoming connections in non-blocking mode and when the selector finds out that there is stuff to read, it changes to blocking-mode? (I know it sounds terrible, but I am a bit desperate.)

Sure, like I said, SocketChannel is blocking by default so you won't need to do anything. I would make the acceptor blocking as well.

> PS: Using Java 8 and it's a TCP-Stream.

No problem, it would be the same if you were using Java 1.4. These libraries haven't changed dramatically in the last 12 years.

Comment: Hello Peter, thanks for the quick reply. I have read an other post where you helped someone about a similar problem. The problem is that the main advantage of NIO (in my opinion) is that you don't have to handle the non-blocking. I am trying to make my application better and more efficient, NIO would be the obvious step. There is really no solution?

Comment: @ElMac 'Main advantage of NIO is that you don't have to handle the non-blocking' doesn't make sense. You don't have to (can't) handle non-blocking with streams either. Your project seems very poorly motivated and very poorly understood.

Comment: @EJP I do have to make them non-blocking (for the end-user). I achieve this by running them on worker threads.

Comment: @ElMac You only have to handle non-blocking with NIO, and only if you enable it.

Comment: @ElMac Do you mean  'for the client'? End users don't care about non-blocking I/O, and neither do most clients for that matter. Threads and non-blocking I/O don't have much to do with each other. This isn't making much sense.

Comment: @ElMac I would optimise whatever your bottleneck is, not change something because it helped someone else. I suggest you benchmark your application but if you are using Java Serialization is almost certainly your problem, it is really bad for performance.

Comment: @ElMac You don't have to make the socket non-blocking, nor should you unless you want to use Selectors (and like pain) or you are busy waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your object(s) using a `ObjectOutputStream` wrapping a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then get the resulting `byte[]` buffer.  Send the buffer over the SocketChannel.

At the other end, extract the `byte[]` buffer from your `SocketChannel`, construct a `ByteArrayInputStream`, and an `ObjectInputStream`, and read your object(s).

Comment: This only works if the serialization fits into a single buffer and was received entire. To make this work in the general case you have to send a length word and then the serialized data, which is a wire protocol change, which implies that you have to upgrade both peers at once. This is really not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it is a hybrid approach, as requested by the OP.  The SocketChannel operates in a non-blocking fashion.  You accumulate buffer fragments until a complete buffer can be constructed.  Then the `ObjectInputStream` operates on the entire received buffer, so it doesn't matter that it is blocking. You are responsible for accumulating partial buffers, which means sending the buffer length ahead of the buffer. I don't see that as being a big hurdle.  As the application is unstable, this division of layers could help determine where the instability originates.

Comment: “*You accumulate buffer fragments until a complete buffer can be constructed*”— that’s the perfect description of blocking I/O. What’s the point of re-implementing blocking I/O atop a non-blocking channel?

Comment: @Holger If it is just one non-blocking channel, not much.  If you have several non-blocking channels, you could have one thread manage all of them, instead of one thread per channel.  Whether or not that makes real sense, of course, would depend on the application, environment, resource limits, etc.

Comment: A thread managing multiple non-blocking channels stops being useful when you start combining it with `ObjectInputStream`s which process arbitrarily complex code during object reconstruction.

Comment: @Holger And yet, my game server which accepted objects from multiple sockets, added "from socket" routing information, and passed the data into a processing queue, turned out to be quiet useful.  As always, TMTOWTDI.